# How to append multiple lines before the last line using echo command

Tags: echo

```
{  
  This is test1  
  this is test2  
  this is test3  
}
```

Now i want append multiple lines before the last line using echo command
Anyone please help me!!!!

My output is look like below

```
{  
  This is test1  
  this is test2  
  this is test3  
  this is test4  
  this is test5  
}
```

Using **Echo** Commands not sed or awk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `head` with `echo` to achieve this

```
  cat <outputfilename> | head -n -1  && echo -e "  this is test4\n  this is test5\n  this is test6\n}"
```

If you want to append the output in a file , just use "`>`" output redirection

```
  (cat <outputfilename> | head -n -1  && echo -e "  this is test4\n  this is test5\n  this is test6\n}") > <RESULTFILENAME>
```

Answer (score 3):

`sed` is the correct way of doing this, even if you said that you for some reason don't want to use `sed`.

The sed script would look like

```
$i\
  this is test4\
  this is test5
```

and you would run that as `sed -f script.sed file`.  The `i` command inserts lines before the addressed line, and the `$` addresses the last line of the file.

As a "one-liner" using GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed -e '$i\' -e '  this is test4\' -e '  this is test5' file
{
  This is test1
  this is test2
  this is test3
  this is test4
  this is test5
}
```

Depending on whether the file is actually a JSON file or in some other structured text format, there may be tools like `jq` that are better suited for manipulating it.

---

To use `echo` as you requested (this also assumes that you are using `head` from GNU coreutils as the `-n` option does not usually take a negative number):

```
{   head -n -1 file
    echo '  this is test4'
    echo '  this is test5'
    tail -n 1 file; } >newfile
```

Comment: Its working but i am using echo command in whole file and now i don't change that if you have answer that please share with me i need that

Comment: @SunilMakwana See added bit at the end.